# pgfplots: Aligning multiple bars and marks horizontally along symbolic X-axis

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, charts

I want to plot average values of some measure as bar charts with error bars and its maximal values as marks above the bars.

I use two separate plots for that now.
The problem is aligning marks with bars: right now all marks are positioned at the same symbolic-X position, whereas I want each mark to be above the corresponding bar (and have the same colour, but that's probably not that big a problem).

Here's a not-so-minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            ymin=0, yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
            symbolic x coords={0,1,2,3}, enlarge x limits=0.15,
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)}, anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
        ]            
        \addplot+ [nodes near coords, point meta=explicit symbolic, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
            table[x index=0, y index=1, y error index=2, meta index=3] {
0   0.1 0.0040  0
1   0.0358  0.0017  224
2   0.0358  0.0017  224
3   0.0358  0.0017  224
};
        \addplot+ [nodes near coords, point meta=explicit symbolic, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
            table[x index=0, y index=1, y error index=2, meta index=3] {
0   0.1 0.0041  0
1   0.0322  0.0016  224
2   0.0321  0.0014  252
3   0.0321  0.0014  266
};
        \addplot+ [only marks] table[x index=0,y index=1] {
0   0.2
1   0.06
2   0.06
3   0.06
};
        \addplot+ [only marks] table[x index=0,y index=1] {
0   0.15
1   0.04
2   0.04
3   0.04
};
        \legend{P1,P2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do this automatically, but you can fix it manually by adding `every mark/.append style={xshift=-6pt}` to the first of the marker plots, and `every mark/.append style={xshift=6pt}` to the second. The value of `6pt` is half the bar width (default value `10pt`) plus half the bar gap (default value `2pt`).

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thank you, @Jake, it is a fine solution, works for me. Only I put the values 12/-12pt to position marks above the center of a bar.

Comment: @wxd: Glad it helps. Using `\addplot+ [only marks,every mark/.append style={xshift=-12pt}]` in your document leads to the marks being shifted too far to the left for me, but if it works for you, that's great

Comment: @Jake, you are right: I've modified the document a bit since I posted the example. Now there's also `[scale=0.6]`, which apparently affects the positioning.

Without it suggested values 6/-6pt work as expected. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Jake Would your comments here make an answer?

Comment: @Jake Can you add an answer?

Comment: @egreg: Done...

Answer (score 3):

You can shift the points by adding `mark options={xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/bar shift}}` to the `\addplot [...]` options:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar,
            ymin=0, yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
            symbolic x coords={0,1,2,3}, enlarge x limits=0.15,
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)}, anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
        ]            
        \addplot+ [nodes near coords, point meta=explicit symbolic, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
            table[x index=0, y index=1, y error index=2, meta index=3] {
0   0.1 0.0040  0
1   0.0358  0.0017  224
2   0.0358  0.0017  224
3   0.0358  0.0017  224
};
        \addplot+ [nodes near coords, point meta=explicit symbolic, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
            table[x index=0, y index=1, y error index=2, meta index=3] {
0   0.1 0.0041  0
1   0.0322  0.0016  224
2   0.0321  0.0014  252
3   0.0321  0.0014  266
};
        \addplot+ [only marks, mark options={xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/bar shift}}] table[x index=0,y index=1] {
0   0.2
1   0.06
2   0.06
3   0.06
};
        \addplot+ [only marks, mark options={xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/bar shift}}] table[x index=0,y index=1] {
0   0.15
1   0.04
2   0.04
3   0.04
};
        \legend{P1,P2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]