# pgfplots: Scatter plot with multiple series side-by-side

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have multiple machines on which I did benchmarks. Now I wan to use pgfplots to show multiple y values (the variance in the measurement) for a single x value (a benchmark parameter) within a single graph. Each machine should get its own "column" in the plot, similar to the effect `ybar` produces with multiple `addplot` commands.

In [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17638) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110717) I already found valuable hints but the legend is broken by the manual mark offset (`xshift`) as it is applied there as well.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  A B   C
  foo   1   2.4
  foo   1   2.1
  foo   1   2.6
  foo   1   2.3
}\dataA

\pgfplotstableread{
  A B   C
  bar   1   2.9
  bar   1   2.2
  bar   1   2.5
  bar   1   2.1
}\dataB

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[only marks, ybar, symbolic x coords={1}, xtick={1}]

    \foreach \id / \offs / \tab in {foo/-4/\noexpand\dataA, bar/4/\noexpand\dataB} {
     \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot+ [every mark/.append style={xshift=\offs pt}] table[x=B, y=C] {\tab};
      \noexpand\addlegendentry{\id}
     }

     \temp
    }

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I already tried to compensate for the `xoffset` by adding `[every mark/.append style={xshift=-\offs pt}]` to the `addlegendentry` command, but without any effect.

How can I get the desired "column effect" in the plot without messing up the legend?

Comment: `legend style={every mark/.append style={xshift=+0pt}}` seems to disable the shifting …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel This does not work for me. If I add your code to `axis` it disables the shifting for the plotted points as well. I have no idea why it does this as the style should only be applied to the legend...

Comment: You’re right, I missed that. A hack-ish solution I found previously was `legend style={legend image post style={/tikz/xshift/.style=}}` which simply disables the `xshift` key for the legend images.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot! BTW, the shorter version `legend image post style={xshift/.style=}` does the same job for me.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key `legend image post style` appends to the `every legend image post` style which is a style that only affects the small legend images (not the legend or the text).

By issuing `/tikz/xshift/.style=` we simply disable the `xshift` key.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
  A B   C
  foo   1   2.4
  foo   1   2.1
  foo   1   2.6
  foo   1   2.3
}\dataA

\pgfplotstableread{
  A B   C
  bar   1   2.9
  bar   1   2.2
  bar   1   2.5
  bar   1   2.1
}\dataB

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[only marks, ybar, symbolic x coords={1}, xtick={1}, 
    legend image post style={/tikz/xshift/.style=}
  ]
    \foreach \id / \offs / \tab in {foo/-4/\noexpand\dataA, bar/4/\noexpand\dataB} {
      \edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot+ [every mark/.append style={xshift=\offs pt}] table[x=B, y=C] {\tab};
        \noexpand\addlegendentry{\id}
      }
      \temp
    }
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]